# Converted JSON Array selection

Tags: javascript, json, xml, node.js

So I made this code in Nodejs:

```
var stemidLength= JSON.memberList.members[0].length;

for (stemidIndex = 0; stemidIndex < stemidLength; stemidIndex++) {
  var steamID64Length= JSON.memberList.members[steamidIndex].steamID64.length;

  for (steamid64Index = 0; steamid64Index < steamid64Length; steamid64Index++) {
    steam.addFriend(steamID64[i]);
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to extract the steamid64s from the xml page here: http://steamcommunity.com/groups/Valve/memberslistxml/?xml=1.
I already converted the xml page into a JSON array.

What is wrong in my code? Getting error:

> cannot read property 'members' of undefined.

EDIT: The JSON extracted array: http://pastebin.com/FECXEKMD

Thanks.

Comment: What is the name of the JSON object you got after the conversion from XML?

Comment: I edited it. Is that ok? or?

Comment: So. var steamUsers=JSON.stringify(data, null, 2); should be good right?

Comment: Hehe cannot read property 0 of undefined now

Comment: Did you try `steamUsers.memberList.members[0].steamID64`?

Comment: It should be `JSON.parse(data)`.

Comment: Unexpected token o at json.parse (native) error.

Comment: How are you converting the XML to JSON?

Comment: Using XML2Js library

Comment: Pasting code on pastebin sec

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5UktnQp3

Comment: I tried the conversion. You don't need to use `JSON.parse` or `JSON.stringify`. The data is already in valid JSON format. You should just assign it to `steamUsers`.

I've also updated my answer to correct a misread property from the `JSON` object.

Comment: HEHE. Cannot read property forEach of undefined. HEHE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102064/discussion-between-gnerkus-and-bogdanb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSON` object is a built-in object for parsing JSON and converting strings to JSON. It does not have a `memberList` property.

I'll refer to the result of the XML to JSON conversion as `steamUsers`.

The IDs can be found in `steamUsers.memberList.members[0].steamID64`. You can add the IDs with the code below:

```
xmlToJson(urlxml, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.err(err);
    }

    var steamUsers = data;
    steamUsers.memberList.members[0].steamID64.forEach(function(memberID) {
        steam.addFriend(memberID);
        console.log(memberID);
    });
});
```

Comment: No. That's just a variable so I see that it's different from what is actually contained in the array.

Comment: Ok trying it. Will it still select the right part from the array?

Comment: I just inspected the XML file and corrected my answer. I apologize for not doing that earlier. Please, see the last line in the answer.

Comment: Uhm I think you got it wrong. Still same error. Ok so the thing is I want to extract each value between <steamID64></steamid64>

Comment: The var is just to count the number of ids between all the <steamid64></steamid64>

Comment: I left a comment on the question. You'll need to post the object you received after converting the XML to JSON.

Comment: Ok updating question right now after I pipe it to a file because console overflow

Comment: Done. Sorry it took a while but my server RDP was crashing